# Remove variation attribute drop downs in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, action, product

I am trying to remove the variations dropdown from a single product page, I have successfully removed the summary using...

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 20 );
```

But I have been unable to find a similar snippet to remove the dropdown.  anyone have an example I can see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the product excerpt you should **normally** use `woocommerce_template_single_excerpt` (with a priority of `20`) like:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
```

To remove (for variable products) the attribute dropdowns, the quantity field and the add to cart button you should use `woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart` (with a priority of `30`) like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'removing_variable_add_to_cart_template', 3 );
function removing_variable_add_to_cart_template(){
    global $product;

    // Only for variable products
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
}
```

> Is not possible to use `remove_action()` **if you wish to remove just the dropdowns** without removing quantity field and add-to-cart button.
>
> If it's the case you will be obliged to manipulate/override the template itself… 
>   See this documentation: [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

The attribute dropdowns from variable products are located in the template WooCommerce template `single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php`.

You will be oblige to insert an `IF` statement with the necessary condition that will feet your needs (at line **`34`** just after the `ELSE` statement in this template).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, all makes sense now